# Django-date incrementation in a list with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-views

New to django/programming, any help is greatly appreciated.  I need help moving through a history of doctor appointments and selecting what immunizations were performed at each appointment, then creating a date when the immunization is due in the future (based on an immunization information table, which has the proper interval of immunizations and will increment from the visit date)

models.py

```
class Immunizations(models.Model):
    immunization = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)**This should probably be an integer field, will change later

class Visit(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patients)
    date_of_visit = models.DateField(null=True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    immunization = models.ManyToManyField(Immunizations)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have been reading the documentation and questions on SO all weekend, but am still very conflicted about what way to go through this.

What I want is:

```
Visit.date_of_visit1
    Visit.immunization1, Visit.date_of_visit1 + Immunization.interval1
    Visit.immunization2, Visit.date_of_visit1 + Immunization.interval2
Visit.date_of_visit2
    Visit.immunization1, Visit.date_of_visit2 + Immunization.interval1
ETC
```

This could go on for years with each visit having different immunizations performed.  I want to maintain a record of which immunization was performed and record the due date, even if that due date has passed.

views.py

```
def visit_profile(request, slug):
    patient = Patients.objects.get(slug=slug)
    try:
            visit = Visit.objects.filter(patient_id=patient.id)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    #Immunization Due Dates
    visitdate = Visit.objects.get(patient_id=patient.id, active=1).date_of_visit
    imm = Immunizations.objects.all()
    visitimm = []
    for immunization in imm:
        due = Immunizations.objects.get(id= immunization.pk)
        duedate = visitdate + timedelta(days=int(due.interval))
        visitimm.append((due, duedate))
    return render_to_response('patient.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Need help with my views.py.  The above works, but only at showing the active=1 visit information.  I can't figure out how to modify/re-do to achieve what I want and be able to access the data in my template file.  I've experimented with __in method, itertools, looping, etc.  Can anyone provide the proper method/direction for doing this?  I will go back and properly setup error catching once I can get the code to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, make interval an IntegerField or maybe rather a PositiveSmallIntegerField since it will   never get a negative value nor a very huge number.
Careful, better don't mix plural and singular in model names, they affect the related names when you traverse your foreign keys which makes it a pain to debug, [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference). I prefer to use only singulars.

Instead of:

```
visit = Visit.objects.filter(patient_id=patient.id)
```

You can simply type:

```
visit = Visit.objects.filter(patient=patient)
```

Try something like this

```
def visit_profile(request, slug):
    patient = Patients.objects.get(slug=slug)
    visitimm = []
    # Looping over all active visit records of the patient in date order
    for v in patient.visit_set
                    .filter(active=True).order_by('date_of_visit'):
        # Looping over each visit's immunizations
        for i in v.immunizations_set.all():
            duedate = v.date_of_visit + timedelta(days=int(i.interval))
            visitimm.append((i, duedate))
    ...
```

Comment: Great! thanks for the help.  In my template, I'm using the ifequal to break out these values to the appropriate date_of_visit line in the template.  This seems to be handling my needs and according to documentation is appropriate, although I'm sure there is a more complex way to handle this as well.